# Declaring a node to be a phantom node breaks connections between sisters in forest

Tags: forest

I wrote a style for `forest` that can be used to connect a tree node with its sibling to the left and to the right. This works very nice for cases like the one below.

[image]

Now I want to connect two nodes at the toplevel (basically two full trees). I introduced a node on top of the two nodes and declared it a phantom node. For reasons I do not understand the connection between the two daughters is not drawn:

[image]

If I replace the phantom node by a real node, everything is fine:
[image]

How can I get rid of the top-most V node and keep the rest?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}


\forestset{dg edges/.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,align=center,base=bottom},
                 where n children=0{tier=word,edge=dotted,calign with current edge}{}
                },
dg junction/.style={edge path={\noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
(!p.east)--(!.west) (.east)--(!n.west)\forestoption{edge label};}}    }

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
dg edges
[V %,phantom
  [V, l sep+=2ex, name=v1
    [N,name=n1 [Robin]]
    [came]
    [Part [in] ] ]
  [Conj,dg junction [and]]
  [V, l sep+=2ex, name=v2 [found]
     [N 
       [Det [a]]
       [chair]]
     [P, name=p [in]
        [N 
          [Det [thirty]]
          [seconds]]]
]]
\draw (v2.south)--(n1.north)
      (v1.south)--(p.north);
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

**Edit:**

The following happens with `\phantom{V}`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}


\forestset{dg edges/.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,align=center,base=bottom},
                 where n children=0{tier=word,edge=dotted,calign with current edge}{}
                },
dg junction/.style={edge path={\noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
(!p.east)--(!.west) (.east)--(!n.west)\forestoption{edge label};}}    }

\begin{document}
bla, bla, bla, bla,bla, bla,bla, bla,bla, bla,bla, bla,bla, bla,bla, bla,bla,    bla,bla, bla,bla, bla,
\begin{forest}
dg edges
[\phantom{V}
  [V, l sep+=2ex, name=v1
    [N,name=n1 [Robin]]
    [came]
    [Part [in] ] ]
  [Conj,dg junction [and]]
  [V, l sep+=2ex, name=v2 [found]
     [N 
       [Det [a]]
       [chair]]
     [P, name=p [in]
        [N 
          [Det [thirty]]
          [seconds]]]
]]
\draw (v2.south)--(n1.north)
      (v1.south)--(p.north);
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

If I add `no edge`to the V nodes, the edges are gone, but there is still the space of the phantom node. The figure looks like below except that the edges at the top are hidden:

[image]

Comment: Use \phantom{V} at the top node.

Comment: Thanks. I did this and added two `no edge` declarations to the V daughters. It works, but the size of the node is still added to the tree, whereas the node with `,phantom` declaration does not use any space.

Comment: How about `\phantom{V},phantom`?

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. The connection between the nodes disappears again.

Comment: So, you want the connection lines between the sisters, but don't want the spaces around the sisters node. If so, use `inner sep=0pt and/or outer sep=0pt` at the sister nodes.

Comment: That did not work. It is not the space around the remaining node, but the space of the phantom node. The picture behaves as if something was there. See my edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20143/discussion-between-jesse-and-stefan-muller).

Comment: Don't use `edge path`. Use the `tikz` key. No edge is drawn because the parent is a `phantom`, so the contents of `edge path` is not executed. If you use `tikz` (without the `\forestoption` bits which you don't need), it will work fine.

Comment: Actually, you can use `[\forestoption{edge}]` for the `\path` and it works fine. And you do want this. You just don't want the label.

Comment: I tried this: `dg junction/.style={\noexpand\draw (!p.east)--(!.west) (.east)--(!n.west);}` But get a complaint that `draw` is an undefined control sequence. Same for `\path`.

Comment: Now, I got it: `dg junction/.style={tikz+={\draw (!p.east)--(!.west) (.east)--(!n.west);}    }` Thanks! I think this will help for my other questions as well. You should add this as an answer to get the points.

Comment: For examples with such constructions in the middle of the tree, one needs an additional `no edge`: `dg junction/.style={no edge, tikz+={\draw (!p.east)--(!.west) (.east)--(!n.west);}    }`

Comment: You need the `no edge` because otherwise the edge is drawn *as well*. In the case of the `phantom`, there is already a `no edge` (which is why defining `edge path` has no effect) and so it isn't necessary. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`edge path` has no effect because the parent is a `phantom`, which effectively implies `no edge` for the children. Use the `tikz` key instead:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{forest}


\forestset{
  dg edges/.style={
    for tree={
      parent anchor=south,
      child anchor=north,
      align=center,base=bottom},
    where n children=0{
      tier=word,
      edge=dotted,
      calign with
      current edge
    }{}
  },
  dg junction/.style={
    tikz={
      \path[\forestoption{edge}] (!p.east)--(!.west) (.east)--(!n.west);
    },
    % no edge,% uncomment if you never want edges with this style
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  dg edges
  [,phantom
    [V, l sep+=2ex, name=v1
      [N,name=n1 [Robin]]
      [came]
      [Part [in] ] ]
    [Conj,dg junction [and]]
    [V, l sep+=2ex, name=v2 [found]
       [N
         [Det [a]]
         [chair]]
       [P, name=p [in]
          [N
            [Det [thirty]]
            [seconds]]]
  ]]
  \draw (v2.south)--(n1.north)
        (v1.south)--(p.north);
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: tikz path]

As Stefan Müller points out in the discussion on the question, to use the same style when the parent is not a `phantom`, you need to add an explicit `no edge` unless, of course, you want both the `tikz` *and* the `edge` paths to be drawn.

Comment: But you shoud add the `no edge` option to the `dg junction` style as well. Thanks a lot! This forest stuff is so cool! It is really great in comparison to what we linguists did the decades before ...

Comment: @StefanMüller Thanks. I've added it as a comment in the code. I guess for this use nobody would want it without that, but who knows?